# How do I copy PDFs onto my iPad and read them there?

Tags: ipad, pdf

I've amassed a collection of books in PDF format (through occasionally buying the [O'Reilly Media Deal of the Day](https://twitter.com/OReillyMedia)), on my MacBook Pro.  I'd like to get them on my iPad, where they'll be more convenient to read.  How do I do that?  Should I look at Dropbox, and download a PDF reader app?  (Do you have one to recommend?)  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I either use the iTunes to iBooks method that Kyle Cronin suggested or use Dropbox if I'm not near my computer or I can't be bothered plugging my iPad in. Dropbox has a send to iBooks command.

Answer (score 10):

iBooks has built-in PDF reader support. Just download it for free from the App Store, then drag the PDFs that you want to copy to your iPad into iTunes. The PDFs will be listed under the "Books" section. Sync your iPad, then when you open iBooks, tap the "PDFs" tab and your PDFs will be listed.

Comment: You can do the same with Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 4):

For finding how to transfer your PDF to your ipad can use this [method](http://www.anypdftools.com/ebook-reading/how-to-transfer-pdf-to-ipad.html). but if your number of PDF is not too much can transfer it to your ipad with mail attachment and use safari to view them.

I think 
[GoodReader for iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) is best pdf viewer for ipad.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of GoodReader but you can use iBooks.  Drag the files to iTunes (and you have to have the newest iBooks first) and then sync them like you sync everything else. Biggest downside is the titles of the pdf's are not shown so if the first page isn't the title you have no idea what you are looking at in iBooks. Beside seeing the filename and being able to read docs from all over the place the other feature about GoodReader I love is that you can lock the zoom in for every page and the text is a readable size and there isn't a lot of waisted space on the margins.