# How can I export PDFs from a PC to a new iPad?

Tags: windows, pdf, ipad, pc

I want to load some of the PDFs I bought from the internet to my iPad from my PC (Windows 7). How can I do this?

I've never bothered about tablets before, but somehow I got an iPad. I did some research in Stack Exchange, but all I could find was information regarding the sending of PDFs from an iPad to a PC; not the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy pdfs to your device you should use iTunes like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EKla_jHA-bM&feature=related)  (just use iTunes for Windows).
You can use iBooks to read pdfs on your device.

Here is related question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/how-do-i-copy-pdfs-onto-my-ipad-and-read-them-there).